# Unable to import Agora SDK into React + Vite

Tags: reactjs, electron, vite, agora

I am migrating React CRA project to **Vite** usage and i encounter one issue with `"agora-rtc-sdk-ng": "4.17.2`" package. After the migration i am getting this error:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "electron" from "node_modules/agora-rtc-sdk-ng/AgoraRTC_N-production.js". Does the file exist?
/Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/.vite/deps/agora-rtc-sdk-ng.js:1:45
1  |  import * as __require_for_vite_TdiBYM from "electron";
   |                                              ^
2  |  import {
3  |    __commonJS
    at formatError (file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:42645:46)
    at TransformContext.error (file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:42641:19)
    at normalizeUrl (file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:40508:33)
    at async file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:40651:47
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async TransformContext.transform (file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:40577:13)
    at async Object.transform (file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:42919:30)
    at async loadAndTransform (file:///Users/user/Desktop/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-4d3eff22.js:53385:29
```

I struggle with finding a solution to that problem for 2 past days, is there any way I can overcome that?

Comment: Are you using Vite with Electron? Can you share the package.json and maybe a code snippet to reproduce this issue?
I created a new Vite project and imported agora-rtc-sdk-ng and it works just fine.